# How to add drop down to my line chart in dash based on a column in dataframe?

Tags: dropdown, plotly-dash

I have cleaned the dataframe and plotting these graphs on plotly and work fine on Dash. I want to insert a dropdown for x-axis (i.e, Y and P for both the graphs separately). I am trying with dcc.dropdown but it's not working.

I have been trying with this but am confused about the dcc dropdown. Any help would be appreciated, I am new to Dash!

```
fig1 = px.line(df_1, x='Y',y=['x','y'])
fig2 = px.line( df_2, x='P',y=['x','y'])


app.layout = html.Div(children=[
# All elements from the top of the page
html.Div([
    html.H1(children='...'),

    html.Div(children='''
       '''
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='graph1',
        figure=fig1
    ),  
]),
# New Div for all elements in the new 'row' of the page
html.Div([
    html.H1(children=''),

    html.Div(children=''' 
        
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='graph2',
        figure=fig2
        ),  
    ]),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is all here https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/dropdown.
Make sure you use dcc.Dropdown instead of dcc.dropdown (lowercase)